# Laravel 5.1 Login Controller Doesnt Work Well

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm new to laravel.  I have a problem with my login control where I can't match the data from my form and the database.

The error message said :

> DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 45: The payload is invalid.

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Hash;
use Crypt;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class LoginControl extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/login')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
        else{
            $email = $request->email;
            $password = $request->password;
            $results = DB::select('select * from users where email = ? and password = ?', [$email,$password]);
            $pass = Crypt::decrypt($request->password);
            if($results == NULL){
                return redirect('/login');
            }
            else{
                return redirect('/');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Router

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/register', function () {
    return View::make('register');
});

Route::get('/login', function() {
    return View::make('login');
});

Route::post('actionregis', 'RegisControl@store');

Route::post('actionlogin', 'LoginControl@login');
```

View

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Laravel Quickstart - Basic</title>

        <!-- CSS And JavaScript -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <!-- Navbar Contents -->
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <!-- New Task Form -->
        <form action="/testing/public/actionlogin" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                <!-- Form Error List -->
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Whoops! Something went wrong!</strong>

                    <br><br>

                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif  
            <!-- Task Name -->
                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="task-email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="task-password" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps your encryption key has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decrypting an unecrypted string (this is why you are getting the error):

```
$pass = Crypt::decrypt($request->password);
```

Why is this even here? `$pass` is not doing anything.

As of now, you are searching for a user with an unecrypted password.

To check if the password is valid, you do **NOT** decrypt the password in DB, you encrypt the inserted one and see if they match.

How are you encrypting the password when inserting it?

Laravel provides a mostly-done authentication by default, you should use it if you don't know what you are doing and want to have authentication as secure as possible. Read about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

To write your own authentication, you should use the [Hash](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#storing-passwords) class:

```
$password = Hash::make('some_password'); // Use this to hash your password (you can store that in the DB)

// To check the password, you parse the user's hashed password from the DB
... // <- parse user here
$hashedPassword = $user->password;

// Password checking
if (Hash::check('some_password', $hashedPassword))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Comment: $user->password =  Crypt::encrypt($request->password);

thats the method i used to encrypt my password

Comment: Okay. So, to check if the passwords are correct, you will most likely want to encrypt the entered password and then search for results with that encrypted password. You don't really want to decrypt something. It should really be not decryptable. Laravel suggests using [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#storing-passwords). I'll edit my answer to include a bit more info on the Hash functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of data maybe the column type in your database is too small and you are therefore getting this error.

Try to set the column to longtext instead of text in your migration and see if that works.